# What was the reason to abandoned Beagle, high CPU usage or high RAM usage?

Tags: mono, lucene, lucene.net

I'm planning a new software for search local text documents (PDF, odt, txt, doc...) AND I would use some code from the abandoned Beagle.

But I'm afraid because I didn't know the reasons why was abandoned...

Anyone remember it or can advice me?

I think beagle was a good LUCENE.NET implementation. What was wrong with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After published the question in twitter to Miguel de Icaza, he responded:

> Miguel de Icaza ‏@migueldeicaza
>
> @AlbertCSharpMan demotivated hackers left to other companies due to
>   anti-Mono flamewars. Linux desktop defunding, politics.

So, is not a coding or programatic matter...